# Turn = into + like holding shift key (icon font)

Tags: php, wordpress, function, slider, customization

I'm creating options for slider arrows on Wordpress customize.php.
I'm using icon font by arrrows.com.
Pressing **shift key** distinguishes left and right arrows.
For example, 'R' is left arrow and 'r' is right arrow.

I want to have one choice changes two css contents, both left and right arrow.
So I used **strtoupper()** to capitalize the letter.
This worked well for alphabet icons, but it is not a solution for these two pairs:
= + and - _

Could someone please help me make these choices to work too?
Thank you for your help in advance.

Here are snipets of my codes:

Controls.php:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('csssection[slider_arrow_shape]', array('default' => r, 'type' => 'option',));
$wp_customize->add_control('csssection[slider_arrow_shape]', array('label' => 'Slideshow Arrow Shape ', 'section' => 'csssections',
            'type' => 'radio',
            'choices' => array(
                'r' => 'arrow 1',
                'n' => 'arrow 2',
                't' => 'arrow 3',              
                )));
```

Functions.php:

```
<?php $csssection = get_option('csssection');
    if ($bodyWidth['slider_arrow_shape'] != $csssection['slider_arrow_shape']) : ?>
    .flex-direction-nav a:before {
                content: '\<?php echo strtoupper(($csssection['slider_arrow_shape'])); ?>';
    }
    .flex-direction-nav a.flex-next:before {
        content: '\<?php echo ($csssection['slider_arrow_shape']); ?>';
    }
<?php endif; ?>
```